# Ruby: select a value in an array in a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I want to iterate through each value of each array of a hash. Normally, to select a value in an array, I would do this:

```
array = ["1", "2"]
array.each do |x| puts x end
```

But how do I iterate through the array if it is in a hash?

This is my code:

```
hash = {1 => {"a1" => ["un", "uno"], "a2" => ["uunn", "uunnoo"]}, 2 => {"b1" => ["deux", "dos"], "b2" => ["ddeuxx", "ddooss"]}}

hash.each do |key, key2, value|
    puts key
    hash[key].each do |key, value|
        puts key
        #insert here the code to iterate through the array
    end
end
```

And this is the most logic thing that I found but that don't work:

```
hash = {1 => {"a1" => ["un", "uno"], "a2" => ["uunn", "uunnoo"]}, 2 => {"b1" => ["deux", "dos"], "b2" => ["ddeuxx", "ddooss"]}}

hash.each do |key, key2, value|
    puts key
    hash[key].each do |key, value|
        puts key
        hash[key][value].each do |value|
            puts value
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Blocks in `Hash#each` iterate with two variables (`|key,value|`), and blocks in `Array#each` iterate with one variable (`|element|`).

Since you have nested hashes and arrays, you need to apply `each` multiple times, with different variable names. `puts` is used with indentation, to better show the structure :

```
hash = {1 => {"a1" => ["un", "uno"], "a2" => ["uunn", "uunnoo"]}, 2 => {"b1" => ["deux", "dos"], "b2" => ["ddeuxx", "ddooss"]}}

hash.each do |id, sub_hash|
  puts id
  sub_hash.each do |key, sub_array|
    puts "  #{key}"
    sub_array.each do |word|
      puts "    #{word}"
    end
  end
end
```

It outputs

```
1
  a1
    un
    uno
  a2
    uunn
    uunnoo
2
  b1
    deux
    dos
  b2
    ddeuxx
    ddooss
```

## Your code

Here's your code with the least amount of modifications :

```
hash.each do |key1, value1|
    puts key1
    hash[key1].each do |key2, value2|
        puts key2
        hash[key1][key2].each do |value|
            puts value
        end
    end
end
```

Note that `hash[key1]` is actually `value1`, and `hash[key1][key2]` is `value2`.